# Valor retornado em consulta SQLITE3 com PHP não é o esperado

Tags: php, sqlite3

Olá, boa tarde, estou tentando realizar um select de um banco SQLite3 que me enviaram com informações, porém o resultado que me é retornado é 0.

Aqui está onde eu quero o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o meu código:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('sqlite:C:\Users\GRUPO\Desktop\dashboard\KISMET-20200423-21-06-02-1.kismet') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from devices';
$resultado = $db->exec($sql);
?>

<div class="w3-quarter">
  <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16">
    <div class="w3-left"><i class="fa fa-comment w3-xxxlarge"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-right">
      <h3><?php echo $resultado ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-clear"></div>
    <h4>Devices Captados</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

O banco me retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O banco não possui servidor, user ou senha, então acredito que a conexão com o banco esteja correta... Alguém pode me auxiliar onde estou errando? Muito obrigado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver após novas pesquisas e leituras do manual, consegui obter o resultado que eu esperava utilizando o parâmetro fetchColumn() que retorna a primeira linha :

```
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:C:\Users\GRUPO\Desktop\dashboard\KISMET-20200423-21-06-02-1.kismet') or die("Erro ao abrir a base");

$nRows = $pdo->query('SELECT count(*) from DEVICES')->fetchColumn(); 

?>
    <div>
      <h3><?php echo $nRows ?></h3>
    </div>
```